# Div element the same size as its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

There is a React application.

The elements structure looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div style="parent">
      <div style="child">
         ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The div with class "parent" has only a `background-color` attribute in css but when it is inspected it also has `display: block`

[image]

the "child" has width: 100% but it doesn't get as big as the parent div.

```
.child {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Why is the child not as wide as the parent if it has 100% width set in its class? If instead of 100% the width is set in `px`, it grows until `1150px`, after that, even if the value is increased, the div doesn't get bigger.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What are all the CSS properties of `.child` and `.root`?

Comment: `.root` has also `display: block` but only in inspect window, in code it has nothing. and `.child` has `width: 100%`. that's all

Answer (score 0):

`div` tag will have by default 100% width. The `display: block` is also the default display of a div. The `width: 100%` on `child` is useless if it has `display: block`. However, if it has `display: inline` then it's normal that it does not fit your parent's width.

Try to inspect your child and check its display. If there is nothing strange for you but it's still not working, provide a working example by editing your question and posting your code so we can help you more :)

Comment: A working [mcve] is required to be posted within his question, preferably with stack snippets,  and NOT any third party site. Doing so will get this question closed.